# VSCode has stopped automatically activating my venv in powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I noticed that my virtual environments are not automatically activated anymore in visual studios integrated powershell terminals.

The settings to activate the terminals are set both in user and workspace settings:
[image]

Additionally, `ExecutionPolicy` is set to `RemoteSigned` in powershell. The has always worked up until (not sure exactly) a few days ago. I actually have no clue what changed. I am working with `venv` (not conda) and tested with serveral projects where I know this was set up correctly and working.

Comment: any relation to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77154846/11107541 ? also, please show your settings as JSON text from settings.json instead of an image.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Please also include the version of the Python extension you have installed, and what version of Python you are using here.

Comment: @starball thanks for the tipps (and sorry for the lack of information in my post), using the pre-release version and restarting windows seems to have resolved the issue. Funnily enought I now got the notification the the env is activated even though it is not shown as `(env)<<path>>` in the terminal ([link with further information](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Activate-Environments-in-Terminal-Using-Environment-Variables))

Comment: okay... but is this a duplicate of that Q&A or not? were you getting a dot with the drive path?

Comment: yes, I think we can close this question.